# Duplicate line on canvas in Android native browser

Tags: javascript, android, html, html5-canvas, android-canvas

I am drawing line on touch move handler in canvas element. The code is bellow,

```
function touchMoveHandler(ev){
        var layerContext = layer.getContext('2d');
        x2 = ev.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
        y2 = ev.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;

        layerContext.clearRect(0, 0, $(layer).innerWidth(), $(layer).innerHeight());

        layerContext.lineWidth = 20;
        layerContext.strokeStyle = "rgba(255,0,0,0.1)";
        layerContext.lineCap = 'round';

        layerContext.beginPath();
        layerContext.moveTo(x1, y1);
        layerContext.lineTo(x2, y2);
        layerContext.stroke();
        layerContext.closePath();
}
```

**layer** is a canvas element. *x1* and *y1* values are taken from touch start handler.

The issue is, getting duplicate line in android native browser on touch move. But the same code is working fine in IOS.

Any one can suggest to fix the duplicate line draw issue?

Comment: Also this tips can be usefull: http://slash-system.com/en/how-to-fix-android-html5-canvas-issues/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `layerContext.closePath();` – because this adds a line back to the starting point. I suppose that iOS just renders them on top of each other, so you can't see it. And Android shows them besides each other.

Comment: Thanks for your Reply. I removed layerContext.closePath() statement, but still getting same issue. On touchMove duplicate line is showing.

Answer (score 0):

It's an [Android bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35474), most often it is triggered by setting an `overflow` on one of the ancestors of the `canvas` element, do you have anything like that in your CSS?

Comment: Thanks robertc. Yes, I have overflow:hidden style for my canvas element in CSS.